# Picking directory without creating list python

Tags: python, memory, directory, generator

I apologize if this is trivial but I'm not sure how to do it

I have a very large directory with many subdirectories (300000+). Inside every directory I want to run a command (lets say I want to open a file and write "Hello World" to it). The problem is I don't want to load up all the directories into a giant list and iterate because of memory issues.

I'm thinking of shutil.move-ing the directories that are done somewhere else but I'm not sure how to pick a directory without loading all of them into a list first (randomly picking a directory would work fine too, not sure how to do that either)

I've read about generators as well but not sure how to implement those either.

Thank you

Comment: `os.scandir` iterates on a directory without creating a list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`os.scandir` iterates through a directory without creating a `list` first (as opposed to `os.listdir`)

Example:

```
import os

dirgen = os.scandir("foo")

print(next(dirgen).name)
```

in that example, the directory `foo` is scanned, but only the first entry is iterated upon (manually) with `next`. It means that if you use it in a loop, it's not going to store directory entries, and even better: you can break out of the loop when you're done (short circuits)